# Laravel FilamentPHP 3 Table | Check-In Check-Out in one row?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I have a MySQL data table called attendance. column names are id, employee_id, date and time.

if employee_id 1 check-in at 8.00 AM and check-out at 5.00 PM on the same day. So I have two records as below.

```
ID  | employee_id  | date       | time
1   |      1       | 2023-10-09 | 08:00:00
2   |      1       | 2023-10-09 | 17:00:00
```

If I want to show check-in & check-out in the same row in the FilamentPHP table, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I know its late but for any one who is looking for this

```
SELECT
  employee_id,
  date,
  MIN(time) as check-in,
  MAX(time) as check-out 
FROM attendance 
GROUP BY employee_id, date;
```